# Is it possible to let the user set a value for filter in Einstein Analytics dashboard?

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards, tableau-crm

Let's assume I am providing a filter widget which allows the user to select multiple accounts. I would need an option to let the user set the filter and next time when he logs in, filter remains same that he has previously selected and he should be seeing the account records according to the filter.

Let's Say, I have an Account Name filter which shows values, A,B,C,D,E.

If an user logs in and he wishes to keep records based on filter values A,C,D. But the filters will be reset the moment he closes the dashboard. What we need is that filter should be set as A, C, D every time he comes back to the dashboard and until he wishes to change the filter.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was launched a couple of years ago. It is called "saved view".

When a user selects a filter, on the upper left hand corner, you will see that an option will appear.

If you select the menu, a dropdown will appear where you can click "save view".

This view can be made the default view.

The referenced documentation will change in the future.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_dashboards_view_create.htm&type=5